# is there any possibility calculate with JButton

Tags: java, swing

when I click button (button is for Coke and 3 Dollars)
i want to that button show me how much a cost a coke.

sorry for English I am learning English as new as Java

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. We need more details before we can answer.

Comment: i am trying to build a GUI by using Java Swing. it has more Frames. when click a button then it opens a new window. in menu frame I want tu put buttons and every button for something. for example JButton cola = new JButton("cola") so, when I click it, it should show me that a cola is 3 dollars. and I need to see summery after more things ordered. thank you for answer

Comment: So you have a class to represent *Cola* and other stuff, with their price as a property?

Comment: exactly. I call it class Beverage

Comment: Do you need to maintain the `Beverage` instances, or just do a summary of their prices? For example you have to show the user what he/she has selected, or you just want to show him the total cost?

Comment: This question is liable to be put to closure as it request us to code almost everything for you to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have no directions as to which classes to use, then you may take a look at the documentation of the following classes which may help:

- If you want to keep track of each `Beverage` the user clicks use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (allows duplicates) which seems convenient in this case. Each time you want the message to be shown, you can then sum up the price of each `Beverage` in the list and show it to the user along with the `Beverage` instances he/she has selected. Or just simply keep track of the summary variable itself if you don't need to keep track of each `Beverage` the user selected.
- Use an [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to the button of each `Beverage`, which will do the summary and then show to the user any message you want (for example the summary of the prices).
- Use a static method of [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html), such as the `showMessageDialog` ones, which will pop a new dialog displaying a simple message (such as the total cost of `Beverage` instances the user has selected).

First of, read some tutorials (such as [*How to Write an Action Listener*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [*How to Make Dialogs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)). Then, read the documentation of each class you want to use while trying to code it yourself. Every time you encounter a problem/failure/difficulty, search it first in the Internet for example or ask someone for directions. If everything fails, then try to post a new question here, explaining the problem, providing the required information, and also the code which fails (if you can).

I'm posting this as an answer as it might be too large for a comment.

If anyone sees any mistake I make in the above instructions, please edit this answer or add a comment and I will edit it myself.

Comment: I tried to post the code I wrote but somehow i could not.. I think I made something..